# Where do I put startup code in Play Framework?

Tags: playframework

I want to run some code on startup to pre-cache some stuff, and would also like to start a Timer to re-cache some things outside the critical path of a web request.  Is this possible with Play Framework, and where so I put this code?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to create a bootstrap job which will be executed by Play at application start time.

```
@OnApplicationStart
public class Bootstrap extends Job {

    public void doJob() {
       //do stuff
    }    
}
```

Read more about how to do this in the [Play Manual](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.1/jobs).

Comment: This appears to be for Play version 1.1.1, and is now deprecated. Do you know of a more recent approach?

Comment: Answer for version 2+ of Play https://stackoverflow.com/a/47715648/340018

Answer (score 31):

For **playframework 2.6+**, please refer to [playframework doc: Eager bindings](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaDependencyInjection#Eager-bindings)

For **playframework 2.0 to 2.5**, use GlobalSettings, as the following code:

```
import play.*;

public class Global extends GlobalSettings {

  @Override
  public void onStart(Application app) {
    Logger.info("Application has started");
  }  

  @Override
  public void onStop(Application app) {
    Logger.info("Application shutdown...");
  }  
}
```

more information, go to [playframework docs: JavaGlobal](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/JavaGlobal)

Comment: [Scala version of the docs, for 2.3.x](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaGlobal)

Comment: up to 2.4 perhaps, 2.5 use di with ApplicationLifecycle

Comment: This is deprecated in 2.6.x: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/GlobalSettings

Answer (score 13):

In **Play 2.4.+** you should use dependency injection with an (optional) lifecycle hook. Play will automatically use any class called `Module` that is in the root package.

For example:

app/ApplicationStart.scala:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import javax.inject._
import play.api.inject.ApplicationLifecycle

// This creates an `ApplicationStart` object once at start-up and registers hook for shut-down.
@Singleton
class ApplicationStart @Inject() (lifecycle: ApplicationLifecycle) {
  // Shut-down hook
  lifecycle.addStopHook { () =>
    Future.successful(())
  }
  //...
}
```

app/Module.scala:

```
import com.google.inject.AbstractModule

class Module extends AbstractModule {
  override def configure() = {
    bind(classOf[ApplicationStart]).asEagerSingleton()
  }
}
```

More documentation of this pattern in [Playframework docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaDependencyInjection#Eager-bindings).

Here's an example [in an application](https://github.com/playframework/play-scala-starter-example/blob/2.6.x/app/Module.scala).

Answer (score 6):

Do not forget that the code shown in the above answers **has to be in the base package of your app** (no package specification). (I am running Play Framework 2.3.2).

Also, **the code will not be run in dev mode until the first HTTP request is made!**

In my case my code is this:

```
import play.*;
public class Global extends GlobalSettings {

@Override
public void onStart(Application app) {
    String message = "Application has started! LOLADA";
    Logger.info(message);
    System.out.println(message);
  }

  @Override
  public void onStop(Application app) {
        String message = "Application shutdown...!!! LOLADA";
        Logger.info(message);
        System.out.println(message);
    }
}
```

Located in the project structure as this:

[image: project structure]

(I am using IntelliJ IDEA).

Comment: Hi, I'm planning to use Play 2.4, it seems asynchronous Job has been removed from it? If that's the case, do you know of something that can accomplish the same?

Comment: "application.global" can be used in the application.conf file to place the global file any where

Answer (score 4):

As of Play Framework, version 2.7.1, in Java:

In `/app/startup/Startup.java`:

```
package startup;

public class Startup {

    public Startup() {

        System.out.println("I ran on startup!");

    }

}
```

In `/app/startup/StartupBinder.java`:

```
package startup;

import com.google.inject.AbstractModule;

public class StartupBinder extends AbstractModule {

    protected void configure() {

        bind(Startup.class).asEagerSingleton();
    }

}
```

Then add this to your `/conf/application.conf` file:

```
play.modules.enabled += "startup.StartupBinder"
```

Comment: Thanks. Thoughts on how to make this run when Play starts (sbt run, etc)? For me it doesn't run until the first browser page load.

Comment: @cloudsurfin It doesn't run until first browser page load due to Play Framework's use of lazy loading in development mode. Alternatively, is to use production mode, instead, to disable the lazy loading. (More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26918545/disabling-lazy-load-in-play-application )

Comment: Much obliged. It is kinda unintuitive to test, to have to refresh a page to get the system to seem to start--especially if it's just a non-browser-based API.

Answer (score 1):

I need prepare some system properties for logger, but it seems logger is init before eager singletons. So I need do it in a customized application loader:

```
import play.api.ApplicationLoader
import play.api.inject.guice.{GuiceApplicationLoader, GuiceableModule}

class MyAppStartup extends GuiceApplicationLoader {
    override protected def overrides(context: ApplicationLoader.Context): Seq[GuiceableModule] = {
        // set system properties for logger configuration template
        super.overrides(context)
    }
}
```

add to `application.conf`:

`play.application.loader = MyAppStartup`

reference:

- https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaCompileTimeDependencyInjection#application-entry-point
- https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/SettingsLogger#using-a-custom-application-loader