# create a database on startup

Tags: scala, playframework-2.1

I am using play 2.1.1.

What I want is, when play starts it should also create a database.

So as said in documentation, in my evolution `1.sql` I added the line `Create Database videos`. But instead I get the below error. (Which is obvious, as it is trying to connect to database which does not exist).

[image]

What should I do, so that play on start up, creates a database and then uses it? Currently it first tries to connect to a database and then call my evolution files.

Answer (score 2):

See: [where-do-i-put-startup-code-in-play-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907603/where-do-i-put-startup-code-in-play-framework)

In there you connect to your mysql with the appropriate user / pw and create a database, you can use DDL for all your tables and predefined data.