# Disabling lazy load in Play application

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.3

By default your Play application will be fully started (compiled, `Global`'s `onStart` called, etc.) only after you do http request to it.

Is there a way to disable this lazy load and make Play app compile code and do startup once application process is run?

PS: I am using Play 2.3.

UPDATE: As Ryan pointed out lazy load happens only in dev. mode. Nevertheless I still need to disable it, despite this is relevant only to apps running in dev. mode.

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way to disable this. The play server starts in dev mode on the first request so that it can recompile when you refresh the page. You may have to employ some trickery like @biesior is suggesting.

Answer (score 1):

Lazy loading only applies in dev mode (`play run`).  Production mode is not lazy.

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Production

Comment: Hmm, ok. I wanted this to ease debugging of some part of my app, so,  guess the question is still relevant - is there a way to disable it in dev. mode?

Answer (score 1):

As Ryan explained it's for dev only.

TIP: IntelliJ Idea has a Play support, by default it opens the new browser window after running in dev mode, which initializes compilation automatically.

Quite sure you can do the same with simple  shell script / batch file.

Answer (score 1):

You can run your application with `testProd` instead of `run` (in the current 2.5 version).  This starts your application in prod mode instead of dev.

If you're running from IntelliJ rather than the Play console, you need to create a new run config, choose SBT Task, and in the Tasks section enter `testProd`.

Answer (score 0):

`play start`. This starts your app in production mode and loads `onStart` when on the app start.