# How to get Playframework to start running app in dev mode without making a request?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.4

I would like to use `activator run` to start the application without making any requests. Currently `activator run` waits for the first request before starting the application. Is there any way around it?

I am aware of `activator start` command. But i want to be in dev mode and use `activator run` instead.

Reasons for this need: my application needs to start reading the data from a database on startup and process the records. So there is no external request being made to the app. And this process needs to be run continuously.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26918545/disabling-lazy-load-in-play-application

Answer (score 0):

Try following command

```
activator ~run
```

**UPDATE:**
Also see https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/4967

Comment: Hey, Mathias. Just to clarify that using "~run" will not start the application without a request. It just compile immediately without requiring a request to be made.

Comment: As @marcospereira mentioned above, i would like the app to be started before the request is made and not just compile.

Comment: @jesukumar why do you need it? Why is important to you to start (in development mode/local environment) the application before a request being made?

Comment: @marcospereira - I need this because of the way i have designed my app. The job for this app is to post process data on a database. All it does is run in a loop, read records on the database and process them. So, there are no external events that trigger the app or make requests to it. So, that is the reason why i need the app to start without any requests.